# How to show direction on react Native Maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to implement a moving car on react native maps but the polyline component doesn’t seems to work fine. Any ideas on how to implement this just like the way Uber does it.

Comment: what about the answer of Mohamed? have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use react native direction and react native maps libraries that take your origin location and coordinate of the another location to draw the direction line

```
    ` <MapView initialRegion={…}>
       <MapViewDirections
       origin={origin}
    destination={destination}
    apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
  />
</MapView>`
```

Comment: Thank you Mohamed, let me try it out.